# How can I open a very, very large image to downsize it?

Tags: resolution, rescaling

I have an image with a 18984x28591px resolution but I can't open it with Paint or with Pixlr Editor to reduce its size.

How can I convert or open this large image on my laptop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not the DPI that is the trouble, it's the dimension of the file probably. It should be more than 1.5 GByte! Is that so?

Comment: size of image is 31.3 MB (32,846,155 bytes)

Comment: Sorry, not the dimension of the file. The size in RAM. If you decode that to normal representation, that needs 18984x28591x3 bytes ~= 1.5 GByte. You will need at least this amount of RAM just to open it. And probably another 1 Gbyte for manipulating it. And 1 GByte for the OS. Something like that.

Comment: it's my personal picture can i send it to you by google drive to reduce the size if that possible and thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, I can try. :-) You could also try IrfanView's batch converter, it might help.

Comment: Try uploading it to Facebook or Flickr or Google Photos. Those services will reduce the size of the image so you can just download it back in reduced format. If that doesn't work, I'd suspect that you have a corrupted file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I used ImageMagick on Ubuntu to resize those big pictures.

```
convert -resize 10% source.jpg dest.jpg
```

It took awhile, but worked with 1 GByte of RAM, the tool created a 4.7 Gbyte swap-like file for itself.

More information is on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images).

Comment: You can also give it a specific resolution, e.g. `convert -resize 1898x2859 ...`

Comment: Also available on OSX.

Comment: There is also a Windows version.

Answer (score 10):

Theoretically, most image formats could be downscaled progressively, without loading the entire image into memory, however I do not know any tools that really implement such feature, except for JPEG: it is special in that you can not only downscale without loading full resolution, but also downscale without decoding full resolution, thanks to the creative use of DCT (JPEG is encoded in frequency domain, which means it does not have to be decoded to the exact same resolution as the original image).

The [default JPEG decoding tool](http://jpegclub.org/djpeg/) (command line, libjpeg-progs package in Linux, look for djpeg.exe for Windows) will downscale huge JPEG before a "regular" application can even finish loading it:

```
djpeg -scale 1/8 huge_image_that_will_not_fit_in_your_ram.jpg >downscaled.ppm
```

I have also seen the downscale-while-loading option in some GUI application, too, but can't recall it at the moment.

### Benchmark!

Comparing the memory usage and processing time of **ImageMagick** vs **djpeg** downscaling a big image (piping to **cjpeg**, so the resulting image is also jpg, for a fair comparison with **convert**)

```
$ display -verbose input.jpg 
input.jpg JPEG 13114x11722 13114x11722+0+0 8-bit sRGB 30.75MB 6.690u 0:06.699

$ /usr/bin/time -f "time=%E mem=%MK" bash -c "convert input.jpg -scale '12.5%' output.jpg"
time=0:10.72 mem=1225844K

$ /usr/bin/time -f "time=%E mem=%MK" bash -c "djpeg -scale 1/8 input.jpg | cjpeg > output2.jpg"
time=0:00.88 mem=1412K
```

**1,2GB vs 1,4MB** and over 10 times slower - and this was on a relatively small 13k x 11k image that could fit entirely in RAM so no swapping occured.

On the other hand, using djpeg for downscaling also has its own limitations: scaling factor choice is limited and the resampling method can't be changed.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try using [Picture Resizer](http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize) on Windows  (I love this tool)

You simply drag and drop the picture on this simple EXE
It is especially useful if you have many pictures to convert as you can do many at a time.

All the config is done through the naming of the EXE which is brilliant IMO

I have never tried it with huge file though.